# jQuery Isotope v2 Fluid Responsive dynamic image size

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I am asking a question about [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co) (jQuery plugin)

I am looking for a solution, where the items (images) fit to the container. Means when resizing the window, the items should be resized too. The item-container should always be fullfilled perfectly, with no space on the right side.

I found a prefect example, thats exactly what I need: http://jsfiddle.net/schmidjon/6Z3sn/
But it doesn't work with Isotope v2, because the smartresize plugin was removed in Isotope v2.

```
var $container = $('.example'),
    margin = 10,
    colWidth = function () {
        var w = $container.width(), 
            columnNum   = 1,
            columnWidth = 0;
        if (w > 1200) {
            columnNum  = 5;
        } else if (w > 900) {
            columnNum  = 4;
        } 
        columnWidth = Math.floor(w/columnNum);
        $container.find('.item').each(function() {
            $(this).css({
                width: columnWidth - margin,
            });
        });
        return columnWidth;
    },
    isotope = function () {
        $container.isotope({
            resizable: false,
            itemSelector: '.item',
            masonry: {
                columnWidth: colWidth(),
                gutterWidth: margin
            }
        });
    };
isotope();
$(window).smartresize(isotope);
```

Can anyone help me, how to run [above example](http://jsfiddle.net/schmidjon/6Z3sn/) in Isotope version 2.x ?

Answer (score 2):

They removed the smartresize function from Isotope v2.

Just add the [smartresize.js](https://gist.github.com/Pushplaybang/3341936) library yourself before your script.

You could also remove the following part from it:

```
// usage:
$(window).smartresize(function(){  
  // code that takes it easy...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The smartresize functionality is removed in Isotope V2. Instead you can use [debouncedresize.js](https://rawgit.com/louisremi/jquery-smartresize/master/jquery.debouncedresize.js)

Include debouncedresize.js an then you can do:

Replace:

```
$(window).smartresize(isotope);
```

With:

```
$(window).on('debouncedresize', isotope);
```

Code example: http://jsfiddle.net/8a8427x3/